# Unexpected condition result

Tags: c#

I have a method:

```
public bool Exists(int levelId, string name, int excludeSubjectIdInCheck = 0)
{
    return _context.Subjects.Any(subj => subj.LevelId == levelId
        && String.Equals(subj.Name, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        && subj.DeletedAt == null
        && excludeSubjectIdInCheck != 0 ? subj.Id != excludeSubjectIdInCheck : true);
}
```

This line evaluates to true:

```
subj => subj.LevelId == levelId
```

This to false:

```
String.Equals(subj.Name, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

This true:

```
subj.DeletedAt == null
```

and this true also:

```
excludeSubjectIdInCheck != 0 ? subj.Id != excludeSubjectIdInCheck : true
```

However, this method is returning true. Why is this? I would expect this would return false given 3 true and 1 false. But when I wrap the last condition in a parentheses like this:

```
public bool Exists(int levelId, string name, int excludeSubjectIdInCheck = 0)
{
    return _context.Subjects.Any(subj => subj.LevelId == levelId
        && String.Equals(subj.Name, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        && subj.DeletedAt == null
        && (excludeSubjectIdInCheck != 0 ? subj.Id != excludeSubjectIdInCheck : true));
}
```

It returns false. But if I look at it, the parentheses shouldn't have made any difference as it didn't group any condition aside itself. What's happening in this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the ternary operator has the least precedence. Without any parentheses, all of

```
subj.LevelId == levelId
    && String.Equals(subj.Name, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    && subj.DeletedAt == null
    && excludeSubjectIdInCheck != 0
```

is evaluated as the first operand for the ternary operator (`?:`). This value then determines which part of the other two operands to evaluate as the result.

The lesson here is to always use parentheses in complex boolean expressions in order to force the evaluation you want. Do not rely on the default precedence in order to avoid unexpected results such as this.

**Note**

A boolean literal as an operand to a boolean expression is almost always extraneous. I'm certain there is a way to simplify your boolean expression to remove the ternary operator entirely. I am too tired to think it all through right at this moment. I think it involves moving the condition for the ternary operator to the beginning of the larger expression.

Comment: Yes, equality, then logical && and only then the conditional ternary operator. [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I understand what happened now. Didn't think the whole of that would evaluate as the first operand. I appreciate the explanation and the suggestions.